SQL Server Agent Job cannot run a query on audit log
I would like to send the result of the following query by mail every 15 minutes.
select 
    event_time, server_principal_name, application_name, 
    database_name, statement 
from
    sys.fn_get_audit_file ('f:\audit\*' , null,null)
where 
    statement not like 'UPDATE STATISTICS%'
    and statement not like 'SELECT%'
    and dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, getutcdate(), current_timestamp), event_time)   
          > dateadd(minute, -15, getdate())
order by
    event_time desc

This query works when logged in.
So I created a job doing that:
begin  
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'default',  
@recipients = '_dba@mymail.be',  
@subject = 'Audit', 
@body_format='HTML',
@query = N'select event_time, server_principal_name, application_name, database_name, statement  from sys.fn_get_audit_file ("f:\audit\*" , null,null)
where statement not like "UPDATE STATISTICS%"
and statement not like "SELECT%"
and DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), event_time) >dateadd(minute,-15, getdate())
ORDER BY event_time DESC',  
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,  
@query_attachment_filename = 'auditResult.html'  
end

Problem: it doesn't work.
Executed as user: TOBACCO\MSA_SQL_Agent$. Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).  The step failed.

If I replace the query by select 1 it works.
If I replace the query by "select event_time, server_principal_name, application_name, database_name, statement  from sys.fn_get_audit_file ("f:\audit*" , null,null)" it fails.
If I run the query in ssms  it works.
If I run the EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail .... in ssms it works.
If I run the job it fails.
Any hint?

Does the SQL Agent have all the relevant permissions? I assume it does not.

Also, don't forget that queries run by dbo.sp_send_dbmail run in the context of msdb unless you specify a value of the database parameter, or use 3 part naming.

Why are you using double quotes inside the query? The way to escape quotes is a double single quote: ''

Oh, I hadn't spotted that, nice @siggemannen . Well that throws the OP's statement "If I run the query in ssms it works" out the window.
